# String Comparison not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, string-comparison

I want to compare two values given

```
<% if (current_user.role.title).eql?( "Test") %>
```

but this comparison doesn't seem to work at all. I checked for the value in  `current_user.role.title` and it prints "Test" ; but when i compare it inside the html page this fails. I also tried doing

```
<% if current_user.role.title == "Test" %>
```

but it doesnt work!! The value `current.role.title` is stored as a Varchar in the database.

Comment: have you tried `if current_user.role.title.to_s == "Test"`?

Comment: Yes still it doesn't work... I did <% Rails.logger.error(current_user.role.title) -%> to check the value being printed in the log and it is Test .... Don't know why it isnt working!!!

Comment: Converted the String to an Array and then compared the value

<% role_Array = (current_user.role.title).split  %>
<% if role_Array[0] != "Test"  %> 

This worked fine..... But still do not know why the direct comparison didn't work!!

Comment: Are you sure it is `'Test'` rather than `' Test'` or `'Test '` or something similar? Try `Rails.logger.error '-' + current_user.role.title + '-'` and `Rails.logger.error current_user.role.title.bytes.count`.

Comment: I tried Rails.logger.error '-' + current_user.role.title + '-' and i got -Test - and for Rails.logger.error current_user.role.title.bytes.count count of 5 Clearly there was a whitespace i missed!!! Thank you @mu

Comment: I expanded on the comment a bit in answer if you want an answer to accept. And remember the `'-' + ... + '-'` trick, it is crude but effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment, it looks like you managed to get a trailing space in your `title`. You're getting `-Test -` when you try:

```
Rails.logger.error '-' + current_user.role.title + '-'
```

and `current_user.role.bytes.count` is 5 so it is just a plain space (or possibly a tab) rather than some Unicode confusion.

You probably want to clean up your data before storing it with [`strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip) or [`strip!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip-21) and you'll want to do the same to any data you already have.

One final check would be to try this:

```
<% if current_user.role.title.strip == "Test" %>
```

The trailing space also explains why your [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) approach behaved as expected:

```
role_Array = (current_user.role.title).split
if role_Array[0] != "Test"
```

Just `string.split` will split (almost always) split on spaces so `role_Array` ended up looking like `['Test']` because `split` would throw away the trailing space.

Comment: Yes, so i just need to do a strip on string rather than doing a split on that string to convert it to array!! That would have been unnecessary and extra lines of code!!

Comment: @Mithun: your `split` ended up being a round about way of doing what `strip` does (i.e. removing the leading and trailing whitespace), `strip` is also a lot clearer.