# Using Rails 3 render_to_string with PrivatePub

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on a project in Rails 3.2 and using Ryan Bates' PrivatePub gem (Faye wrapper).  I'm having an issue passing the result of a render_to_string into the javascript of the Publish method.  So far I haven't had any luck looking through Google, the render_to_string docs, or the Faye docs.

In my controller I have the following:

```
def my_action
  html_text = render_to_string :partial => 'my_partial', :formats => [:html]
  puts html_text
  PrivatePub.publish_to("/#{my_channel}", "$('#my_id').html('#{html_text}');")
end
```

This doesn't work (the div on the subscribed page doesn't update).  However, assigning a string of the same content that's in my_partial to html_text, it works fine (div updates):

```
def my_action
  html_text = "<h3>Testing this</h3>" #This is the only change from above
  puts html_text
  PrivatePub.publish_to("/#{my_channel}", "$('#my_id').html('#{html_text}');")
end
```

Looking at the server log, I can see that in either case, the "puts html_text" output looks exactly the same.

Not sure it matters, but my controller only responds to json, and I'm using curl to push test POSTs to this action.

The partial is simply:

```
<h3>Testing this</h3>
```

I must be missing something simple here, but I can't figure out why render_to_string would give me a different result that simply assigning a string variable.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output in each case?

Comment: In both cases the server log shows `<h3>Testing this</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, though I'm not exactly sure why.  Here's what I did:

Based on some discussion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857779/string-comparison-not-working-in-ruby) I added the following to the code so I could see better what was happening:

```
    html_text = render_to_string :partial => 'my_partial', :formats => [:html]
    test_text = "<h3>Testing this</h3>"
    puts "****************************************"
    puts html_text
    puts test_text
    puts html_text.bytes.count
    puts test_text.bytes.count
    puts "-" + html_text + "-"
    puts "****************************************"
    PrivatePub.publish_to("/#{my_channel}", "$('#my_id').html('#{html_text}');")
```

In the server log, I noticed that the html_text had one more byte than the test_text.  I also noticed that the ending "-" on the html_text was being displayed on a separate line.

```
-<h3>Testing this</h3>
-
```

So I added

```
html_text.strip!
```

after the render_to_string call and suddenly it works!  Now the problem is figuring out exactly what byte was at the end that caused this not to work (because I can't just let that go!).  Anyone have any ideas on what that might be?

**EDIT**

I figured out what was causing the issue, so I'll explain that in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

I expanded my partial to look like this

```
<h3>Testing this</h3>
One
Two
```

and things stopped working again.  That's because the string had `/n` in it.  So I replaced  `html_text.strip!` with `html_text.gsub!(/\n/, '<br/>')` and now everything works fine.  Sometimes deep thinking just obfuscates the simple answer!

Not sure if this is the best Railsy way to go about this, but it got the job done.  If anyone knows a better way to do this, I'd love to hear!